# Spring Data: adding additional auditing attibutes to JoinTable with @CreatedBy for ManyToMany relationships

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

What is the best practice to add additional attributes to a join Table for Many to Many relationships in Spring Data?
More precisely I would like to add some informations for logging with  @CreatedBy, @CreatedDate, @LastModifiedBy and @LastModifiedDate.